# Running `unison -repeat watch` yields filesystem watcher error

Tags: synchronization, unison

I'm trying to sync a folder in my host OSX to a VM running Ubuntu. (laravel/homestead). This is the command I run on my host:

`$ unison ssh://vagrant@192.168.10.10//home/vagrant/www ~/unison/www -repeat watch`

which produces the following output

```
Contacting server...
Connected [...]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server
Fatal error: Server: Unexpected response 'Usage: unison-fsmonitor [options] root [path] [path]...' from the filesystem watcher (expected VERSION)
```

On my localhost:

```
$ unison -version
unison version 2.48.3
$ unison-fsmonitor
VERSION 1
```

On my VM:

```
$ unison -version
unison version 2.48.3
$ unison-fsmonitor
Usage: unison-fsmonitor [options] root [path] [path]...
This program monitors file system changes on all given (relative to root) paths
and dumps paths (relative to root) files to a file. When launched, this file is
recreated. While running new events are added. This can be read by UNISON
to trigger a sync on these files. If root is a valid unison profile, we attempt
to read all the settings from there.
```

For my localhost, I installed unison via homebrew, and downloaded the `unox.py` file [from github](https://github.com/hnsl/unox) and installed it to `/usr/local/bin/unison-fsmonitor`.

For my VM, I used `ppa:eugenesan/ppa` for unison, and downloaded [the source for version 2.48.3](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison//download/releases/stable/unison-2.48.3.tar.gz) from the unison website to get a copy of `fsmonitor.py`, which I placed under `/usr/bin/unison-fsmonitor`.

Unison without `-repeat watch` works without issues.

I get the same output if I try to run the same command (reversing the ssh) form inside the VM. I've read that the unison-fsmonitor should comply with the protocol described in `/src/fswatch.ml` and this doesn't seem to be the case for the default `fsmonitor.py` script. Am I missing something? Is there another script that should be used for the unison-fsmonitor executable instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile Unison from source, there is a separate executable `unison-fsmonitor` that is created. When you run this `unison-fsmonitor` it prints `VERSION 1` and then waits as expected. Just compile Unison on your VM and use that executable instead of the `fsmonitor.py` script.

You can see in the [change-log for Unison 2.48.3](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#news) that they created a new file-watcher utility. It's not clear to me why `fsmonitor.py` is included in this release if you are supposed to use the new utility. Or maybe the new utility and the python script actually perform different tasks ... ?

Comment: Thanks! Compiling from source on the VM solved the issue as you stated.